# Seemingly Random errors in writing with retrbinrary()

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download a text file from an ftp server and its working, however when I was doing a sense check on the data it seems to randomly miss-read the data and write two lines when I am expecting one, example:

```
DYO8 6    GB1925    5 20582
DYO8 8    GB1882    1 4717
DYO8 8    GB744
     2 12003
DYO8 8    GB1925    3 15199
DYO8 8    GB1970    4 19102
```

I can't see a pattern in what is causing this. But I would be expecting this:

```
DYO8 6    GB1925    5 20582
DYO8 8    GB1882    1 4717
DYO8 8    GB7442    1 2003
DYO8 8    GB1925    3 15199
DYO8 8    GB1970    4 19102
```

My code is below, newfiles is a list of files to be read

```
def writeline(line):
    file.write(line + "\n")

for filename in newfiles: 
    local_filename = os.path.join(r"c:\local\path", filename)    
    try: 
        file = open(local_filename, "wb") 
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, writeline)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % local_filename
        file.close()
    file.close()
```

Just had a suggestion from a colleague that this might be through the whole reading from and ftp server issue. In that it catches and send through a special character or somewhat and causes the read to brain fart and start a new line. Does this help anyone see a possibility? Perhaps a way to check the line is correct before moving on?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and looked at alternatives to writing in retrbinary() and just got rid of the whole separate function thing. As I still have no idea what caused the initial issue I cannot explain why this worked, however I can see that it does work. Current code:

```
for filename in newfiles: 
    local_filename = os.path.join(r"c:\upsaccesspoints", filename)    
    try: 
        file = open(local_filename, "wb") 
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, file.write)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        print 'ERROR: cannot read file "%s"' % local_filename
        file.close()
    file.close()
```

I'd like to say that's the last time I take advice from the internet on how to code, but that'd be a blatant lie.